# Avoiding cached data with NSURLRequest

Tags: iphone, http-headers, nsurlrequest

I had this problem while developing an app where the request was a simple URL and the response returned XML.

I used the `[NSURLRequest sendsynchronousrequest]` and the request header `Cache-Control` had default `max-age` value of `81769` by default. Because of this, the response i got was not the latest XML but an old XML. Safari and IE returned an old XML but Chrome and Firefox returned the updated latest XML.

I guessed the reason IE and Safari returned the old XML was because the `Cache-Control` max age was `81769` whereas the same header when inspected in chrome or Firefox returned `0`.

So i manually set the `max-age` value as `0` for the header field and got the latest XML as response.

I want to know if this is the best solution or is there any other reliable method to get the latest response.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at the set of [`NSURLRequestCachePolicy`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSURLRequestCachePolicy) enum values.

Specifically, you can create an `NSURLRequest` object using the `+[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:]` method and specify `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` or something similar for the cache policy.